# Preserve grid-gap of sidebar when using a sticky position

Tags: css, css-grid, grid-layout, sticky

I'm using a CSS-grid layout and with some help, I managed to "fix" both the header and the left sidebar using position: sticky. However, I would like to know if there's a way of preserving the grid-gap (top margin) of the sidebar in a way it doesn't touch the header.

Here's the link to my CodePen: https://codepen.io/fergos2/pen/MWgLqgL?editors=1100

The same code can be found below without the lipsum.

Thanks in advance for helping this newbie!

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #eee;
  
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: min-content 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 15px;
  
  grid-template-areas: "head head head"
                       "leftbar main rightbar";
  
  & > * {
    background-color: pink;
    color: #ggg;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
  }
}

  .pd {
    padding: 15px;
  }
  
  .header {
    grid-area: head;
    
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
  }
  
  .left-sidebar {
    grid-area: leftbar;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    
    .left-inner {
      position: -webkit-sticky;
      position: sticky;
      top: 60px;
    }
    
    .box-1 {
      color: red;
      border: 1px solid purple;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
    
    .footer {
      color: green;
      border: 1px solid purple;
    }
  }
  
  .main-content {
    grid-area: main;
  }

  .right-sidebar {
    grid-area: rightbar;

     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     justify-content: flex-start;

      .box-2 {
        color: red;
        border: 1px solid purple;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
      }

      .box-3 {
        color: green;
        border: 1px solid purple;
      }
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header class="header pd">Header</header>
  

    
    <div class="left-sidebar pd">
      <div class="left-inner">
        <div class="box-1 pd">
        Box-1
      </div>
      <footer class="footer pd">
        Footer
      </footer>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="main-content pd">
      Main content 
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="right-sidebar pd">
      <div class="box-2 pd">
        Box-2
      </div>
      <div class="box-3 pd">
        Box-3
      </div>
    </div>

  
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

As suggested in the comments, the code below does the job:

```
header {box-shadow: 0 15px #eee;}
```

Comment: `header {box-shadow: 0 15px #eee;}` would fake it , your three columns are scrolling up behind the header, the gap remains there but scrolls up too :( .

Comment: That's brilliant! Thanks @G-Cyr! That will do the trick...